# Uploading image.jpg from iPhone / iPad to html / php form using Mobile Safari

Tags: php, javascript, ios, upload

I have a simple html / php form that allows the user to select a photograph on their computer and upload it to the web site.  I am using input type=file in the html and it works perfectly on a computer.  When I try to access the page on an iPhone or iPad, input type=file locates the image but calls it "`image.jpg`" and the php upload function can not find the correct address.  Is there some php or javascript or ??? function that I can use that would run on the web site (NOT on the iPhone / iPad using UI Kit or objective c or ...) that would "translate" the iOS "address" to something php could use?  I do not want to create an app that would run on the iPhone or iPad.  In other words, the user would access the web page through mobile Safari and the image would be transferred to the php section.  Perhaps, just the string representation of the image could be sent and then recreated in php. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is here at all.  Please try to explain your issue another way.

Comment: The html form uses input type=file to locate the file to be uploaded.  I then use move_uploaded_file in php to upload the file.  In any browser on a computer, the upload works perfectly.  On an iPad or iPhone (using iOS 6.+) using mobile Safari, input type=file finds the file but loads " image.jpg ".  I can not use that "name" in move_uploaded_file.  I would like to be able to upload that particular file without writing a special app to run on the iPad or iPhone.

Comment: Use any name you want then.  Send an alternate name along with the form submit or ajax request.

Comment: I am sorry but I guess I am still not clear.  I do appreciate your response and your taking an interest.  It seems that all files on the iPad are referred to as " image.jpg " since there is not a file system on iOS 6.  I need to upload the image that is on the iPad to my web site but if I use " image.jpg " nothing happens.  If I wrote an app for the iPad, it would be easy to send the image up.  However, I do not want to require users to get another app for the iPad so I need to figure out the "url" for the image on the iPad so I can use that in php ( move_uploaded_file ).  Thank you again.

Comment: If "nothing happens" then there is an error in your PHP code.  You'll need to show that code and provide more detail if you want some assistance.

Comment: Oh my.  Now I feel like a complete moron.  The image on the iPad was much larger than I thought and I was much more impatient than I should have been.  It works fine on the iPad.  It is just VERY SLOW with a larger file.  I just need to rename the file when I save it on my web site.  Thank you very much - I knew there was no error in my PHP code.